# PHP, SPL, ArrayAccess Interface

Tags: php, arrays, spl, arrayaccess

I am trying to understand the idea behind ArrayAccess Interface,

I dont understand what each method is about, If those methods(functions) are "built in" functions and ArrayAccess Interface(also "built in") is only "make sure" i am going to implement those "built in" methods(functions)

I am trying to understand what does each of thoes functions is doing with our code "Behind the scenes".

```
function offsetSet($offset, $value);
function offsetGet($offset);
function offsetUnset($offset);
function offsetExists($offset);
```

If i understand ArrayAccess is a Built In interface that Containing seals to implement, when we implement them we only implement references to thoes built in functions, I will be happy if some one can please help me get this right.

Comment: This class is well documented here http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you implement that interface, then the object acts like an array. e.g., if `$foo` is an instance of a class that implements `ArrayAccess`:

`$foo['bar'] = 42` calls `offsetSet('bar', 42)`.

`echo $foo['bar']` calls `offsetGet('bar')`.

`unset($foo['bar'])` calls `offsetUnset('bar')`.

`isset($foo['bar'])` calls `offsetExists('bar')`.

You never explicitly call the functions offset* yourself. It happens implicitly when you access the object as an array.

Comment: Thank you so much Matthew, I will be very happy if you confirm my understanding about this subject, The Array Interface is a "built in interface" this interface containing signatures of those functions, those functions are references to a "built in" functions that automatically respond when we access the object as a array, and thank you so much for your answer i was trying the manual and didnt understand this interface, if you can please just confirm, have a nice day Matthew.

Comment: The interface is built-in with those four function signatures, but the PHP programmer must actually implement them. The behavior of automatically calling offset* functions when accessing them like an array is also built-in... something that you cannot do with your own interfaces. (There are a few built-in interfaces that when implemented similarly affect core PHP features.)

Comment: Thank you Matthew, if i got this right the is only functions and parameters signatures, and the behavior of automatically calling offset*,but tell me please, this behavior is it only saying when you are access as array call offset*, what i am saying is this behavior is only refers to the functions name? what means that it is my responsibility to set the functions to act as i want them to, and thanks again.

Comment: The programmer must write the offset* functions to do something useful. e.g., Usually `offsetSet($key, $val)` is something like `$this->data[$key] = $val`. PHP takes care of the rest. Write some test code and you will see that it works.

Comment: Matthew Thank you so much really i tryed to understand it until now, i didnt understand the manual and i was searching for answer like yours, have a nice day, and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

While comparing `ArrayAccess` to `SimpleXMLElement` (an internal class not implementing it), I was curious, too. The interface is well documented in the manual already, so I wanted to highlight some differences in specific with offset types.

But first of all a boilerplate example implementation of a class implementing `ArrayAccess` giving output when accessed:

```
/**
 * ArrayAccess Example
 */
class ExampleArrayLikeAccess implements ArrayAccess
{

    /**
     * Whether a offset exists
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetexists.php
     * @param mixed $offset - An offset to check for.
     * @return boolean true on success or false on failure.
     *
     * The return value will be casted to boolean if non-boolean was returned.
     */
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        echo "  - offsetExists(", $this->varString($offset),")\n";
    }

    /**
     * Offset to retrieve
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetget.php
     * @param mixed $offset The offset to retrieve.
     * @return mixed Can return all value types.
     */
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        echo "  - offsetGet(", $this->varString($offset),")\n";
    }

    /**
     * Offset to set
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetset.php
     * @param mixed $offset The offset to assign the value to.
     * @param mixed $value The value to set.
     * @return void
     */
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        echo "  - offsetSet(", $this->varString($offset), ", ", $this->varString($value), ")\n";
    }

    /**
     * Offset to unset
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetunset.php
     * @param mixed $offset  The offset to unset.
     * @return void
     */
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        echo "  - offsetUnset(", $this->varString($offset),")\n";
    }

    /**
     * helper to give a variable dump in form of a string
     */
    private function varString($var) {
        ob_start();
        var_dump($var);
        return trim(strtr(ob_get_clean(), ["\n" => '', "\r" => '']), ' {}');
    }

}
```

Running some usage-examples with it. I have left notes in form of comments. It should be pretty self-explaining:

```
$like = new ExampleArrayLikeAccess();


/* offsetExists */

// indexes/keys that behave similar to PHP arrays:

isset($like[1]);    # integer stay integer
# offsetExists(int(1))

isset($like['1']);  # string like an integer - converted to integer
# offsetExists(int(1))

isset($like['01']); # string unlike an integer - stays string
# offsetExists(string(2) "01")

isset($like[TRUE]); # booleans are converted to integer
# offsetExists(bool(true))

// indexes/keys that differ to PHP arrays:

isset($like[1.1]);     # a float stays a float (double)
# offsetExists(double(1.1))

isset($like[NULL]);    # NULL stays NULL
# offsetExists(NULL)

isset($like[array()]); # array stays array
# offsetExists(array(0))

isset($like[$like]);   # object stays object
# offsetExists(class SxeLikeAccess#2 (0))


/* offsetGet */

// indexes/keys behave the same as with offsetExists:
$like[1];    # offsetGet(int(1))
$like['1'];  # offsetGet(int(1))
$like['01']; # offsetGet(string(2) "01")
// ...


/* offsetSet */

$like[1] = 'value';    # index/key behaves the same as with offsetExists
# offsetSet(int(1), string(5) "value")

$like[] = 'value';     # index/key is NULL
# offsetSet(NULL, string(5) "value")

$like[NULL] = 'value'; # index/key is NULL
# offsetSet(NULL, string(5) "value")


/* offsetUnset */
unset($like[1]);       # index/key behaves the same as with offsetExists
unset($like[NULL]);    # same for NULL
```

Key differences to standard PHP arrays are that you can use not only integer and string as offsets.